# onsort datatable not invoke function in js lwc

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

For datatable column sorting, I have following datatable:

```
<lightning-datatable title="MY ORDERS" data={data} columns={columns} key-field = "SalesDocument" onsort={updateColumnSorting} sorted-by={sortedBy} sorted-direction={sortedDirection} onrowaction={handlePdfAction} hide-checkbox-column>
                                </lightning-datatable>
```

And in js i have this function:

```
updateColumnSorting(){
      ///this.sortedBy = event.detail.fieldName;
      //console.log("this is sort by"+this.sortedBy);
      //this.sortedDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
      console.log('function invoke');
      //this.sortData(this.sortedBy,this.sortedDirection);       
  }
```

this is columns:

```
@track columns = [{
    label: "Order",
    fieldName:'SalesDocument',
    type: 'url',typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'SalesDocument' }, target: '_blank'},
    },
    {
    label: "Amount",
    fieldName: 'NetAmount',
    type: 'text',
    },
    {
    label: "Order Date",
    fieldName: 'OrderDate',
    type: 'Date',
    },
    {
    label: "Status",
    fieldName: 'OrderStatus',
    type: 'text',
    },
    {
        label: 'Order Confirmation',
        type: 'button-icon',
        initialWidth: 75,
        typeAttributes: {
            iconName: 'utility:print',
            title: 'Print',
            variant: 'border-filled',
            alternativeText: 'Print'
        }
    }
  ];
```

But the updateColumnSorting function not invoke when i clicked on column.This is pretty much simple but dont know why its not invoke.

Comment: sortable property should be true for columns on which sorting is required. If property is not set as true then sort function will not be called. Please share columns variable.

Comment: Sir i edit my question and provide columns..thanks for your valuable response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sortable property should be true for columns on which sorting is required. If property is not set as true then sort function will not be called.

```
@track columns = [{
        label: "Order",
        fieldName: 'SalesDocument',
        type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: {
                fieldName: 'SalesDocument'
            },
            target: '_blank'
        },
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: "Amount",
        fieldName: 'NetAmount',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: "Order Date",
        fieldName: 'OrderDate',
        type: 'Date',
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: "Status",
        fieldName: 'OrderStatus',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Order Confirmation',
        type: 'button-icon',
        initialWidth: 75,
        sortable: true,
        typeAttributes: {
            iconName: 'utility:print',
            title: 'Print',
            variant: 'border-filled',
            alternativeText: 'Print'
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: Ohh great man! Its works fine now.Thank You so much.